Initializing a vector with a class that has a pass-by-reference constructor parameter and saves that reference as a member
I'm trying intending to create a single instance of a type that gets shared among the items in a vector. Each of the vector's item types requires a pass-by-reference parameter in the constructor but I can't seem to get the vector to initialize properly.
//The type of each item in the vector
class PollingConfig_t
{
    public: 
        PollingConfig_t(DebugPrinter_t& _debugPrinter) : _debugPrinter(debugPrinter) {}
    private:
        DebugPrinter_t& _debugPrinter; //Reference to the global instance of DebugPrinter_t
}

And for the actual globals:
DebugPrinter_t DebugPrinter(true); //One instance shared among vector items
std::vector<PollingConfig_t> PollingConfigs(4, PollingConfig_t(DebugPrinter)); //4 instances of PollingConfig_t, each with reference to DebugPrinter.

This doesn't compile and give me an error:
error: use of deleted function 'PollingConfig_t& PollingConfig_t::operator=(const PollingConfig_t&)'
HOWEVER, I can get it work seemingly as intended if I simply remove the ampersand in the _debugPrinter declaration.
    private:
        DebugPrinter_t _debugPrinter;

But wouldn't this create copies of the original instance DebugPrinter for each of the vector's items? I mean if _debugPrinter is declared as a DebugPrinter_t instead of DebugPrinter_t& it's no longer a reference, right?

References as data members are nasty at best. Use a pointer: DebugPrinter_t *_debugPrinter;.

const and reference members should be avoided.  DebugPrinter_t& can be replaced with DebugPrinter_t*

vector does a lot of copying, moving, assigning, and move-assigning as you put items in, take them out shuffle them, sort them, etc..., and classes with references and const members don't copy or assign simply enough to have default copy, move, assignment and move assignment operators. You have to write code to tell the program exactly what to do when copied/moved/assigned, and sometimes you'll find you can't do it at all.

The code shown compiles for me in gcc, clang, and msvc - after fixing the typo in your PollingConfig_t constructor. (https://godbolt.org/z/rEef1f4K9) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error in action. The error is not coming from your initialization of the vector, so it must be coming from your usage of the vector later on. How are you actually using the vector that requires copying your PollingConfig_t objects?

Reference members are problematic because, once initialised to refer to an object, a reference cannot be changed (e.g. via assignment) to refer to another object.   This is the main reason that having a reference member causes a class to have a deleted assignment operator.   This clashes with a requirement of standard containers that contained objects have copy and/or move semantics (constructor and assignment operator).   If you must, use a pointer member instead (but bear in mind that default-generated assignment/copy will do shallow rather than deep copies).

Mark the day. This is the day you learn that vector can only store “value types”. That of course depends on how you define op= and copy constructor to copy stuff, but chances are, once you have a reference inside your class is very hard to understand what a copy really is. Presumable the reference should be pointer or (unlikely) the reference might be an assumed invariant thing during the lifetime of the object (hence op= needs a custom definition).

Vector of objects that contain references

std::vector need to copy/move the elements in it (e.g when it is elarged and require reallocation).
In your case this is a problem because your element contains a reference which once initialized cannot be changed.
Adding operator= is not a good solution because you will still have a problem assigning the reference.
And you are correct that having DebugPrinter_t _debugPrinter is also not good because it will cause copies to be made.
You can solve it in various ways, e.g.:

Use a pointer instead of a reference:
class PollingConfig_t
{
public: 
    PollingConfig_t(DebugPrinter_t * pDebugPrinter) : m_pDebugPrinter(pDebugPrinter) {}
private:
    DebugPrinter_t * m_pDebugPrinter; // pointer to the global instance of DebugPrinter_t
}

Then initialize the vector with:
DebugPrinter_t DebugPrinter(true); //One instance shared among vector items
std::vector<PollingConfig_t> PollingConfigs(4, PollingConfig_t(&DebugPrinter)); // NOTE the & to take the address of the global object to initialize the pointer

And in order to use the global object from within PollingConfig_t, use: m_pDebugPrinter-> ....

Use a std::shared_ptr:
The std::shared_ptr support multile owners, and also takes care of the lifetime of the object.
class PollingConfig_t
{
public: 
    PollingConfig_t(std::shared_ptr<DebugPrinter_t> pDebugPrinter) : m_pDebugPrinter(pDebugPrinter) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<DebugPrinter_t> m_pDebugPrinter; // shared_ptr to the global instance of DebugPrinter_t
}

You need to change the creation of the global object and the vector as following (note the usage of std::make_shared for creating the global object):
std::shared_ptr<DebugPrinter_t> DebugPrinter = std::make_shared<DebugPrinter_t>(true); //One instance shared among vector items
std::vector<PollingConfig_t> PollingConfigs(4, PollingConfig_t(DebugPrinter)); // NOTE the shared_ptr is passed by value. It keeps a reference count on the object.

Using the global object from within PollingConfig_t is the same as with a raw pointer: m_pDebugPrinter-> ....

Use a singleton for the DebugPrinter_t object:
Since you have only one instance shared by all entities, you can use the signleton design pattern.
This way you don't even need to add a member to each PollingConfig_t because all element will have access to the singleton.
I mentioned this the last since it is somewhat discouraged.
But since you have a global object anyway (which is the common claim against singletons) it might fit.



You need to define PollingConfig_t::operator=(): https://godbolt.org/z/EMWGnqvco
class PollingConfig_t {
   public:
    PollingConfig_t(DebugPrinter_t& _debugPrinter)
        : _debugPrinter(_debugPrinter) {}
    PollingConfig_t& operator=(const PollingConfig_t& p) {
        if (this != &p)
        {
            std::destroy_at(this);
            std::construct_at(this, p);
        }
        return *this;
    }

   private:
    DebugPrinter_t&
        _debugPrinter;  // Reference to the global instance of DebugPrinter_t
};

EDIT: Thanks for doug's comment. I've corrected the code.

This won't work because the reference isn't initialized by _debugPrinter = p._debugPrinter; It assigns to what the reference refers to. What you have to do is replace the whole object. It requires c++20 or higher. See this for a way to impliment copy assignment for objects that contain const's and/or references.

As Remy Lebeau pointed out in comments, your proposed code does compile and the vector can be initialized that way.
Something else in your usage of the vector is causing the error. The compiler is saying that you need to provide a copy assignment operator, since the compiler can't synthesize one for a reference member. You can't re-seat the reference, which makes it difficult, so if you really need to do assignments you might want to use a pointer instead.

C++20 has modified the rules a bit. You can now reseat references and consts by replacing the entire object. It requires a relatively simple method

@doug Thanks for the comment, I was not aware that had been introduced. A little more elegant than placement new-ing over yourself

Yep. And constexpr so you can use it at compile time.
